# Why are sine and cosine identities always true (and thus sentences) even though they have free variables?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

In mathematics, we often see statements such as $\sin ^2x + \cos^2 x = 1$.

Notice that this is not a sentence, as the variable $x$ is free. But we all agree that this statement is true, given the usual interpretations of the symbols. How can we square this with the claim that sentences are the formulas that can be either true or false?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In practice, a statement such as

$$
\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1
$$

serves as a convenient abbreviation for

$$
\forall x \, \sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1.
$$

In other words, free variables like $x$ are governed by implicit universal quantifiers. Most of the time, writing out all quantifiers increases  clutter and hurts readability, so it is avoided.

Comment: This answer is perfect.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)

Comment: But in first order logics we have distinct formulas like $x=x$ and $\forall x(x=x)$. The first is not looked at as an abbreviation of the second in that context.

Comment: Indeed. Logic has intrinsic interest in distinguishing the two cases, so the trade-off between precision and clarity plays out differently. Outside of logic there are also cases where quantifiers are made explicit, for example where relative position of existential and universal quantifiers matters (e.g. definition of uniform continuity). I merely said that "writing out *all* quantifiers" is unwise and hence avoided.

Answer (score 1):

A formula that is always true does not have to be a sentence.

We have e.g. formula $x=x$. True in every model and looked at as logical axiom.

Dealing with sine and cosine we are busy in some model $\mathfrak A$.

There we can easily interpret function symbols in such a way that for distinct terms $t$ and $s$ we have:
$$\mathfrak A\vDash t=s[\alpha]$$
for every $\mathfrak A$-assignment $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

It follows from the definition of satisfaction in a structure:

$$\mathcal{M} \models \phi \\\Longleftrightarrow \text{ for all assignment functions } v: \mathcal{M}, v \models \phi$$

i.e., a formula is true in a structure if and only if it is true under all variable assignments in that structure.

The definition of satisfaction thus renders open formulas as implicitly universally quantified, and we have

$$\mathcal{M} \models \phi \text{ iff } \mathcal{M} \models \forall x_1 \ldots \forall x_n \phi \text{ (where } x_1, \ldots, x_n \text{ are the variables occurring free in } \phi \text{)}$$

that is, a formula is true in a structure exactly when its universal closure is.

So

$$\sin ^2x + \cos^2 x = 1$$

is a distinct formula from but has the same structure-level truth conditions as

$$\forall x (\sin ^2x + \cos^2 x = 1)$$